# draw 6 cards out of poker deck, what is the chance to see at least one of diamond J Q and K？

Tags: probability

I have started to learn probability from the ground up.

My attempt:

1 - C(6, 51) / C(6, 54) = 1 - 18009460/25827165 = 1 - 69.73% = 30.27%

I don't think I am right, this answer looks too big a percentage to me. 
Maybe my method is wrong.

Comment: A normal deck has $52$ cards.  otherwise, the logic looks fine.

Comment: There are 4 each of J,Q,K so 12 in deck. So it should be $\binom{52-12}{52}$ Also combinations usually have larger number on top.,

Comment: @coffeemath  OP specified diamonds.

Comment: @lulu Right... Still the larger numbers should be on top.

Comment: @coffeemath what is your expression called? I am not from a math background so I need to google to evaluate this expression, thanks!

Comment: @MichaelMac try "binomial coefficient".

Comment: @coffeemath is right concerning notation.  The larger number comes first.  The notation is $C(n,k)=\binom nk$.  thus $C(49,6)=\binom {49}6=13983816$

Comment: So it's $1-C(49,6)/C(52,6)=346/1105\approx 31.3122$%